deploy laravel 11 on share host (Hostinger). Css issues
I have deployed my Laravel 11 app on a subdomain on Hostinger Shared Hosting. However, the app is not loading the CSS and JS files.
Here is the folder structure
public_html/myapp/

I updated the .env files for production and ran the npm run build command
I zipped the app and uploaded it to hostinger inside the myapp folder
The .htaccess in the public_html/myapp/public/.htaccess looks like this
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

The index.php files inside the public_html/myapp/public looks like this
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
(require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleRequest(Request::capture());

When I uploaded the file, the Css and javascript from the
public_html/myapp/public/build/assets is not loading. so the site CSS/js is broken
when I view the source code, this is what I get
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/css/app.css" /> 
Instead of <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/app.[hash].css" />
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 @vite('resources/css/app.css','resources/js/app.js')
</head>

What am I missing?

Did you get the vite manifest after the build step? Sometimes, it does not produce one and you have to force it. EDIT: Oh, and double check the output of the DIR in the main index.php (you can just var_dump(__DIR__) at the top of it.
